# What is the program break in memory?

Tags: c, sbrk, brk

I am into reading reading a article talking about allocating space for pointers that does not say exactly what the PROGRAM BREAK" is but mentions it. I need to know what the program break is. If I create say a pointer to a memory space with malloc..ie

```
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(100);
```

is the PROGRAM BREAK the beginning or the end? Is it the ADDRESS of p[0] or p[99] THX

Comment: The "program break" (which is controlled by [`brk` and `sbrk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)) isn't really used these days. It's mostly of historical interest now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unless you are implementing your own memory allocator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the program break is the end of the initialized data segment, and, as such, it is in general *elsewhere*:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(100);
    printf("%p %p %p\n", ptr, ptr+100, sbrk(0));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x744010 0x744074 0x765000
```

The actual value depends on the strategy used by the runtime memory allocator (aka `malloc`).

Comment: Some implementations of `malloc` don't even use the break, but only `mmap`